# How can we formally define a Pseudo-Random Shuffle function?

Tags: protocol-design, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-permutation

My question is related to: [When we turn Random shuffle to Pseudorandom Shuffle](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33226/when-we-turn-random-shuffle-to-pseudorandom-shuffle)

The idea is to permute the elements in vector $\mathbf{v}$ pseudorandomly, where $|\mathbf{v}|=n$;

I am aware that we can use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=364540) for pseudorandom shuffle (in fact we replace the random generator with a pseudorandom one). So we can use a key: $k$, when we want to pseudorandomly shuffle the vector.

Let the pseudorandom shuffle be: $\pi (k,\mathbf{v})$

1. How to formally define the pseudorandom function? For instance, do we need to say pseudorandom shuffle must be indistinguishable from random shuffle?
2. Is there any textbook or paper has already defined it?

Comment: A block cipher is a pseudorandom shuffle. Some use the name block cipher only when the set shuffled has $2^b$ elements, where $b$ is the block size; but the definition has been generalized in [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). I see no reason why a pseudorandom shuffle's formal definition would differ from that of a block cipher extended to input/output domain of arbitrary finite size.

Comment: @fgrieu Thank you for the comment. Then why would people use  Fisher-Yates shuffle instead of using a block cipher. Is that because the shuffle algorithm is faster than a block cipher?

Comment: The Fisher-Yates shuffle gives a perfect block cipher, and is useful and common for actual implementation of one over a small input/output domain. For domain too large for Fisher-Yates, there's the option of an imperfect but computationally secure block cipher constructed otherwise, like [Feistel's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher).

Comment: @fgrieu Do you happen to have a reference regarding using the Fisher-Yates shuffle as a block cipher that way? I'm interested in learning more.

Comment: @Ella Rose: the [Fisher-Yates shuffle is also known as Knuth's shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). In [_A Synopsis of Format-Preserving Encryption_](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/synopsis.pdf), Phillip Rogaway presents it as one of the simplest way to implement FPE for tiny domains, and gives several references for this shuffle.

Comment: Isn't "shuffle" just a synonym for *permutation*? Pseudorandom permutations are well-studied.

Comment: "The Fisher-Yates shuffle gives a perfect block cipher" Only when you have an ideal random number source. Programming using a non-secure RNG (outside the context of cryptography, obviously) usually uses Fisher-Yates for lists that fit in memory because the weak RNG makes it the faster option. Also, it's simpler and more well known. (Which is really understating the knowledge barrier in this scenario.)

Comment: Although. We don't have to shuffle $v$. We can populate set $V$ via brute force from a TRNG using an appropriate discriminating algorithm. Therefore we'd create a truly random permutation, albeit inefficiently (but not if you want a truly random result). Hence not impossible as I do this for 8 bit derangements using `/dev/random`.